# How to make string matching case insensitiv [text()="sTrInG"] in python (lxml)?

Tags: python, string, xpath, case-insensitive

I have this xpath pattern:

```
tags = doc.xpath('/html/body//a[text() = "' + name.encode('utf8') + '"]/@href'
```

This returns the url of every -tag with name `name` as text in it. Is it possible to get a case insensitiv matching of `name`?

### Edit

When trying @Shelhamer solution I get:

```
>>> a_tag_list = html_string.xpath('/html/body//a[lower-case(text()) = "' + author_name.lower() + '"]/@href')
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1459, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:40530)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 324, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:113864)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 242, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:113063)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:112894)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Unregistered function
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: pythonistas would usually prefer `doc.xpath('/html/body//a[text() = "%s"]/@href' % name.encode('utf8'))` over `str.__add__`

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I love nitpick, from whom I can learn. ;) So, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using the lower-case function:

```
tags = doc.xpath('/html/body//a[lower-case(text()) = "' + name.encode('utf8') + '"]/@href'
```

A helpful list of functions is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: When trying your code I get a `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Unregistered function`. What does that mean? The full trace is in the question.

Comment: In that case, try the translate function instead:
translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

in place of lower-case(...)

Comment: What about special caracters like `áöä` and so on. I guess I have to specify them too? Like in `translate(text(), 'ÄÖÜ...', 'äöü...')`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I would assume yes. I haven't had to deal with that particular case myself, so I can't give you further tips concerning non-ascii characters.

Comment: Workaround: I solved the problem by creating two lists. One contained all the `text()` and one contain all the `hrefs`. I did the `.lower()` in python and found by string comparison in python the `href` I needed, since the `gref` has the same index in its list as the `text()`.

Comment: FYI-you are likely getting the Unregistered function error because `lower-case()` is an XPath 2.0 function and the python implementation only supports XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

No. XPath is case sensitive. [You could try normalising the text, by converting everything to lower case to avoid this issue](http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/07/06/84229.aspx).